# Is it possible to trigger AMPscript from link in Email?

Tags: javascript, email, salesforce, exacttarget, ampscript

I have ExactTarget for Salesforce enabled and I'd like to create a Task record whenever someone clicks on a particular link in my email template.

I am aware that AMPscript allows me to create a record in SFDC through 'CreateSalesforceObject' and wanted to know if there was a way to trigger such code through clicking a 'Meet Rep' link in my email.

My AMPscript code as of now (I am aware this is static, but I'm using this for testing purposes):

```
%%[ var @id set @id=CreateSalesforceObject("task", 3, "WhoId","003w0000018b98p","Subject", "A Customer Has Requested a Rep Meeting", "Owner", "00520000001Vp3O", "Description", "A customer has requested a meeting with a Rep"))]%%
```

Basically, I send email -> client receives email -> client clicks 'meet rep' link on email -> AMPscript is triggered -> Task Record is created in SFDC

Is it possible to make this happen? If so what code do I need to add to my HTML email template as to trigger the AMPscript? Can anyone provide a pointer to how this can be written?

Thank you for your time and I'm extremely grateful for any help!

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe you can attach AMPScript to links that way.  You'll need to have an intermediate ET landing page that accepts the subscriber data and then executes the [CreateSalesforceObject()](http://help.exacttarget.com/en-US/documentation/exacttarget/content/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/ampscript_functions_for_use_with_salesforcecom/#CreateSalesforceObject) function.  All of the subscriber personalization strings would be available to you on the landing page if you link to it using the [MicrositeURL()](http://help.exacttarget.com/en-US/documentation/exacttarget/content/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/microsite_and_landing_page_ampscript_functions/#MicrositeURL) in your email.

You didn't mention what you wanted to occur when someone clicks on the link.  Some kind of confirmation message on a landing page seems appropriate.

[Landing Pages](https://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/microsites/landing_pages/)

[Microsite/Landing Page AMPScript Functions](https://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/microsite_and_landing_page_ampscript_functions/)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a cloud page with that ampscript and insert a link to that page in your email.

The cloud page consist of some basic html saying "Thank you", so each time a customer visits the page a task will be created. You can also use cookies to disable multiple tasks created by the same user.

Here is an example:

```
%%[
  var @visited
  var @id

set @cookieName = 'ZSfreecheck' 
set @subject = HTTPRequestHeader("Cookie")
set @pattern = Concat(@cookieName, '=(.*?)(;\s|$)') 
set @cookieValue = RegExMatch(@subject, @pattern, 1)
set @visited = @cookieValue
 IF EMPTY(@visited) THEN
  set @id = CreateSalesforceObject("Case", 8, 
  "Status", "New", 
  "Subject", "ZS free check-up email", 
  "Type", "Custom fix", 
  "Origin", "Email",
  "Reason", "Other",  
  "AccountId", v(RequestParameter("AccountId")), 
  "OwnerID", "00G0Y000000PMtb",
  "Description", "Free check-up proposal for customer. Must convert into a sale."
  )
 ELSE
  set @id = @cookieValue
 ENDIF
]%%
```